# pass value from With..as into a function (POSTGRESQL)

Tags: postgresql

In Postgresql, I am trying to pass the result of a query into a function but I am getting

> SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "pakito" does not exist   Position:
> 176

```
WITH pakito AS(
    select array(select job_id from job)
 ),
 updating_job AS(
     select internal_update_job_progress('xavier-tenant', pakito)
 )
 
 
 select * from pakito
```

Anyone has any idea why it wouldn't work and how to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `FROM pakito` in the second CTE.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up while simplifying the query for here. job_array and pakito are the same (I have just edited)

Comment: Oh, then that is a trivial omission.